# SSRS 2008 R2, using Lookup, Parameters and Row Visibility to do something impossible, it seems

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I'm using SSRS 2008 R2 and building a report with Report Builder 3.0. I have 3 parameters that are all used to restrict my data from the same column, the diagnosis code. What my user needs is the ability to restrict up to three levels of potential matches.

For example, they want to be able to select all diagnosis LIKE "Z%" and have those displayed. They want to be able to select all diagnosis LIKE "Z%" and LIKE "W%" and have those displayed but NOT any of those that are ONLY LIKE "Z%". They also want to be able to select all diagnosis that are LIKE "Z%" and LIKE "W%" and LIKE "U%" but NOT those that are ONLY LIKE "Z%" or ONLY LIKE "Z%" and LIKE "W%".

This has proven to be extremely difficult, basically impossible in one SQL query. I tried using UNION but it was still limiting me. Currently, I have created 3 seperate datasets, DXCode1, DXCode 2 and DXCode3, each one connected to a different parameter, allowing the 2nd and 3rd parameters to be NULL. I've got 3 rows in a table on my report to display my diagnosis information. Diagnosis Code (DXCode1) row 1 shows anything LIKE Z%. Diagnosis Code (DXCode2) row 2 shows anything LIKE W% via LOOKUP to my second dataset. Diagnosis Code (DXCode3) row 3 shows anything LIKE U% via LOOKUP to my third dataset.

I have a hidden column in each row that checks the length of my possible matches.

```
=LEN(Lookup(Fields!ChartNumber.Value, Fields!ChartNumber.Value, Fields!DiagnosisCode.Value,"DXCode2"))
```

ChartNumber is my unique identifier. If there a match on those in DXCode1 and DXCode2, it means there's something I want to show. I use Row Visibility to hide any rows that have a value of 0. I repeat this logic on the next row down as well.

This works to do anything when they are looking for more than one type of diagnosis code. When they ONLY want diagnosis that are LIKE "Z%", I can't use the same logic or else it hides everything. I need something that will hide DXCode2 and DXCode3 if are NULL but will still allow me to hide DXCode1 only if it standing alone and still show my DXCode1, DXCode2 and DXCode3 if they match.

I hope that I have explained myself correctly and that someone can help with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I got it. I used a text box first to show true or false on the report for all possible combinations. I used this statement:

```
=IIF(LEN(Lookup(Fields!ChartNumber.Value, Fields!ChartNumber.Value, Fields!DiagnosisCode.Value,"DXCode1"))>0,"True","False")+IIF(LEN(Lookup(Fields!ChartNumber.Value, Fields!ChartNumber.Value, Fields!DiagnosisCode.Value,"DXCode2"))>0,"True","False")+IIF(LEN(Lookup(Fields!ChartNumber.Value, Fields!ChartNumber.Value, Fields!DiagnosisCode.Value,"DXCode3"))>0,"True","False")
```

This told me if DXCode1 had a value and DXCode2 and DXCode3 did not, it was TrueFalseFalse
If DXCode1 and DXCode2 had a value  and DXCode3 did not, it was TrueTrueFalse
If DXCode1 and DXCode2 and DXCode3 had a value, it was TrueTrueTrue
If DXCode1 and DXCode3 had a value and DXCode2 did not, it was TrueFalseTrue

I needed code on my first row visibility telling it if it was TrueFalseFalse and a parameter had been selected (LEN(Parameters!DiagnosisCode.Value)>0), I needed to hide it or if it was TrueFalseTrue and a parameter had been selected, I needed to hide it. That resulted in this code.

```
=((IIF(LEN(Lookup(Fields!ChartNumber.Value, Fields!ChartNumber.Value, Fields!DiagnosisCode.Value,"DXCode1"))>0,"True","False") + IIF(LEN(Lookup(Fields!ChartNumber.Value, Fields!ChartNumber.Value, Fields!DiagnosisCode.Value,"DXCode2"))>0,"True","False")  + IIF(LEN(Lookup(Fields!ChartNumber.Value, Fields!ChartNumber.Value, Fields!DiagnosisCode.Value,"DXCode3"))>0,"True","False")) = "TrueFalseFalse" AND LEN(Parameters!DiagnosisCode2.Value) > 0) OR ((IIF(LEN(Lookup(Fields!ChartNumber.Value, Fields!ChartNumber.Value, Fields!DiagnosisCode.Value,"DXCode1"))>0,"True","False") + IIF(LEN(Lookup(Fields!ChartNumber.Value, Fields!ChartNumber.Value, Fields!DiagnosisCode.Value,"DXCode2"))>0,"True","False")  + IIF(LEN(Lookup(Fields!ChartNumber.Value, Fields!ChartNumber.Value, Fields!DiagnosisCode.Value,"DXCode3"))>0,"True","False")) = "TrueFalseTrue"AND LEN(Parameters!DiagnosisCode2.Value) > 0)
```

I also ended up having to change the other rows to accomodate this same logic, The report now works.